# Matlab - hist function doesn't display anything

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure

I would like to display 5 histograms having 5 different vectors of size (1,264) (1,262) (1,262) (1,264) (1,262). For each vector, I simply do

```
[count, bin] = hist(Vi)
```

where Vi is the name of the vector.

I obtain

```
count = 2     6     2     6    22   202     3     2     4    15
bin = -0.0959   -0.0763   -0.0567   -0.0370   -0.0174    0.0023    0.0219    0.0416    0.0612  0.0808

count = 2     0     0     8     6    26   191     0     9    20
bin = -0.1352   -0.1116   -0.0879   -0.0643   -0.0406   -0.0169    0.0067    0.0304    0.0540    0.0777

count = 2     6     0     2     6   202     0     0    12    32
bin = -0.1219   -0.0995   -0.0772   -0.0548   -0.0324   -0.0100    0.0123    0.0347    0.0571    0.0795

count = 4     2     6    20   190     2     0     4     6    30
bin = -0.0641   -0.0478   -0.0315   -0.0152    0.0011    0.0174    0.0337    0.0499    0.0662    0.0825

count = 4     0     0     2     6    16   192     0     6    36
bin = -0.1362   -0.1123   -0.0884   -0.0646   -0.0407   -0.0168    0.0071    0.0310    0.0548    0.0787
```

but each time the images are empty, they don't even have axes.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the documentation for [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

> `[nelements,xcenters] = hist(___)` returns an additional row vector,
>   `xcenters`, indicating the location of each bin center on the x-axis. To
>   plot the histogram, you can use `bar(xcenters,nelements)`.

So the answer is simply to plot the data with `bar(bin,counts)`.

Comment: It works, thank you! But shouldn't the `hist` command display something too? With simple vectors it does..

Comment: Again, check the doc. It does display the histogram when called without output arguments (e.g. `hist(data)`). When called with output arguments, such as in your case, it doesn't display anything but simply returns the values.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command without saving the output:

`hist(vi)`

The documentation doesn't explicitly say it, but if you assign the output to some variables, it suppresses the plot because it assumes that you just want the data.
See the MATLAB documentation for [hist()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html#btsgtr1-1).

Note that the `historgram()` function behaves differently in this regard.  It always creates a plot.  But its optional output is a *Histogram* object.
See the MATLAB documentation for [histogram()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html)